# Proving Norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis

Is $\lVert (x,y) \rVert = (\lvert x \rvert^{1/2} + \lvert y \rvert^{1/2})^2$ a norm on $\mathbb{R}^2?$

My attempt:

i) Positive Definite: $\lVert (x,y) \rVert = (x^{1/2}+y^{1/2})^2 \ge 0$; equality holds if and only if $x,y = 0$

ii) Homogeneous: $\lVert \alpha(x,y) \rVert = (\alpha^{1/2})^2(x^{1/2}+y^{1/2})^2 = \lvert \alpha \rvert (x^{1/2}+y^{1/2})^2 = \lvert \alpha \rvert \lVert (x,y) \rVert$

iii) Triangle Inequality:

This is the part I am stuck at. I keep making mistakes on it. How do I set up the triangle inequality? I know it's very simple, but I just can't get it for some reason.

Thanks.

Comment: $\|(1,0)+(0,1)\|=\|(1,1)\|=4>1+1=\|(1,0)\|+\|(0,1)\|$, so the triangle inequality isn't satisfied, it's not a norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note. $\|(1,1)\|=4$ which is greater than $\|(1,0)\|=1$ and $\|(0,1)\|=1$, hence this is not a norm as the triangle inequality isn't satisfied.

Comment: So, I understand that providing a counterexample is sufficient for the problem as stated. For the sake of knowledge: if I wanted to prove (in a more general way) that the triangle-inequality is not satisfied, would that be possible? I.e., for some arbitrary $\lVert (x_0,y_0) + (x_1,y_1) \rVert$

Comment: There's no such thing as "more general" when something is false. In this case, if it's "arbitrary", you can't disprove the triangle inequality because $\Vert 0 + 0 \Vert \leq \Vert 0 \Vert + \Vert 0 \Vert$.

Comment: Understood. Thanks